# At most one subgroup of every order dividing $\lvert G\rvert$ implies $G$ cyclic

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, cyclic-groups

> Suppose we have a finite group $G$ of finite order $n$. For every $d\mid n$, $G$ has at most one subgroup of order $d$. Show that $G$ is cyclic.

Comment: What sort of results are you allowed to use? Do you know Sylow's theorems? Do you know something about $p$-groups?

Comment: Thank you for your question! It is good practice on this site to add a bit of information on the context your question came up in, and to share your own work on it. It's also fine if you state that you're completely lost -- the information is helpful for answerers to gauge their answer. For more information on asking a good question on this site, see [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/9959/43351).

Answer (score 13):

Let $a_d$ denote the number of elements of order $d$ and $u_d$ the number of cyclic subgroups of order $d$.
Then $a_d = \varphi(d) u_d$, where $\varphi$ is the Euler phi function.
Reason: A cyclic group of order $d$ contains exactly $\varphi(d)$ elements of order $d$, and each element $g$ of order $d$ is contained in exactly one cyclic subgroup or order $d$, namely $\langle g\rangle$.

The assumption on $G$ implies $u_d \leq 1$ for all $d\mid n$. We get
$$
n = \lvert G\rvert = \sum_{d\mid n} a_d = \sum_{d\mid n} \varphi(d) u_d \leq \sum_{d\mid n} \varphi(d) \cdot 1 = n\text{.}
$$
So the "$\leq$" is in fact an equality, implying $u_d = 1$ for every divisor $d$ of $n$. In particular $u_n = 1$, and hence $G$ is cyclic.

Comment: Did you mean $a_d=\phi(d)u_d$?

Comment: @Prototank Yes, I corrected it. Thank you for letting me know!

Comment: @azimut The assumption on G is that there's at most one subgroup of order d|n, not necessarily a cyclic subgroup, right?

Comment: @HariPrasadPoilath Right. Notice that I only used $u_d \leq 1$, which follows from the original assumption. (At most 1 subgroup of order $d \implies $ a forteriori: at most 1 cyclic subgroup of order $d$.)