# Proving $G$ is cyclic given situation.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I am trying to solve the following problem:

Let $G$ be a finite group. Suppose for all $n\in\mathbb{Z}^{+}$ divides the $|G|$, $G$ have at most $n$ elements $g$ of $G$ with $g^{n}=1$. Prove $G$ is cyclic.

I tried to use Lagrange's theorem but wasn't able to proceed further. Does anyone have idea how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $H\leq G$ such that $|H|=n$, for all $h\in H$ we have $h^n=e$. Therefore for all $n$, there must be at most one subgroup of $G$ with order $n$.

[Then, see the answer here.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/525643/at-most-one-subgroup-of-every-order-dividing-lvert-g-rvert-implies-g-cyclic)